# Quick question: Determinant bundle is Cartier?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, reference-request, vector-bundles

$X$ is an algebraic surface (i.e. compact complex, which embeds in a projective space). $V$ is a vector bundle of rank 2 over $X$. Why is $\det{V}=\mathcal{O}_X(D)$ for some divisor $D$? Is there a general statement? Thank you.

Comment: If $X$ is any scheme (not necessarily compact, projective, smooth etc.) and $V$ is any vector bundle (of arbitrary rank) then $\det V$ is always a line bundle and line bundles always corresponds to a Cartier divisor and thus it is of the form $\mathcal{O}_X(D)$ for a Cartier divisor $D$, though $D$ is not unique.

Comment: @Mohan You need some hypotheses, don't you? They're almost always satisfied but they're there. I think Hartshorne says integral or projective over a field is okay.

Comment: @Hoot No hypothesis is necessary. Certainly quasi-projective is more than enough

Comment: @Mohan I think Kleiman gives an example in his article _Cartier divisors versus invertible sheaves_. Certainly it's okay in the OP's setting, I agree.

Comment: Please! Why is the above true? Thank you.

Comment: @H,C Look near the end of II.6 in Hartshorne.